# How to make a plot from summaryRprof?

Tags: r

This is a question for an university assignment.

I was given three algorithms to calculate the GCD that I already did. My problem is getting the Rprof results to a plot so I can compare them side by side.

From what little understanding I have about Rprof, summaryRprof and plot is that Rprof is used like this:

```
Rprof() #To start
#functions here
Rprof(NULL)  #TO end
summaryRprof() # to print results
```

I understand that plot has many different types of inputs, x and y values and something called a data frame which I assume is a fancy word for table. and to draw different lines and things I need to use this: http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/r/

what I cant figure out is how to get the summaryRprof results to the plot() function.

```
> Rprof(filename="RProfOut2.out", interval=0.0001)
> gcdBruteForce(10000, 33)
[1] 1
> gcdEuclid(10000, 33)
[1] 1
> gcdPrimeFact(10000, 33)
[1] 1
> Rprof(NULL)
> summaryRprof()
?????plot????
```

I have been reading on stack overflow that and other sites that I can also try to use profr and proftools although I am not very clear on the usage.

The only graph I have been able to make is one using plot(system.time(gcdFunction(10,100)))

As always any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gcd functions must be something you've coded separately as they aren't a part of base R. Here is a contrived example to show you how to get the data into a usable format for further processing and plotting.

First, you need to pass `summaryRprof()` a filename to process. In your example, this would be `summaryRprof("RProfOut2.out")`.

This will return the summary statistics for your previous code. Since we need to do further processing on these statistics, let's assign it to a new object:

`sumStats <- summaryRprof("RProfOut2.out")`

This returns a list object with 4 elements:

```
> str(sumStats)
List of 4
 $ by.self        :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ self.time : num [1:2] 1.97 0.25
  ..$ self.pct  : num [1:2] 88.7 11.3
  ..$ total.time: num [1:2] 1.97 0.25
  ..$ total.pct : num [1:2] 88.7 11.3
 $ by.total       :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ total.time: num [1:3] 1.97 0.25 0
  ..$ total.pct : num [1:3] 88.7 11.3 0
  ..$ self.time : num [1:3] 1.97 0.25 0
  ..$ self.pct  : num [1:3] 88.7 11.3 0
 $ sample.interval: num 1e-04
 $ sampling.time  : num 2.22
```

At this point, I'm assuming you are going to be interested in one of the first two data.frames. I prefer the graphics in `ggplot2` over base graphics, but you can certainly achieve most things with base graphics...I just have more experience with `ggplot2`. Here's one approach to plotting the data for the `by.self()` dataframe that was generated:

```
require(ggplot2)

byself <- sumStats$by.self

byself$functions <- rownames(byself)

m <- melt(byself, id.var = "functions")

qplot(functions, value, data = m, fill = variable, geom = "bar", position = "dodge")
```

That makes a plot that looks like this:
[image]

And for completeness sake, here is the contrived code I made up for the example. I know not very creative, but gets the job done:

```
Rprof("Rprof.out", interval = 0.0001)
x <- rnorm(10000000)
y <- x ^ 2
Rprof(NULL)
sumStats <- summaryRprof("Rprof.out")
```

Comment: I already have the GCD functions what I am missing is what you are describing.

Answer (score 6):

There are two packages that visualize `Rprof` output:

- [profr](http://cran.r-project.org/package=profr) by Hadley Wickham
- [proftools](http://cran.r-project.org/package=proftools) by Luke Tierney

On a Unix/OS X system with `graphviz` installed you can use a nice Perl script by Romain Francois that is on the [R Wiki page on profiling](http://wiki.r-project.org/rwiki/doku.php?id=tips:misc:profiling:current).

All this is described with examples in my *Intro to HPC with R* tutorials you can find e.g. [here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/presentations.html).

Comment: The other package worth noting here is [profvis](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/profvis/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for addition. That package didn't exist when the question, and answer, were written.